# Spark-Hudi: Save as table to Glue/Hive catalog

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hive, aws-glue, apache-hudi

**Scenario:**
Store Hudi Spark dataframe using `saveAsTable(data frame writer)` method, such that **Hudi supported table with**  `org.apache.hudi.hadoop.HoodieParquetInputFormat` Input format schema is automaticaly generated.

Currently, `saveAsTable` works fine with normal (non Hudi table), Which generates default input format.
I want to automate the Hudi table creation with the supported input file format, either with some overridden version `saveAsTable` or other way staying in the premise of spark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hudi **DOES NOT** support `saveAsTable` yet.

You have two options to sync hudi tables with a hive metastore:

### Sync inside spark

```scala
val hudiOptions = Map[String,String](
...
  DataSourceWriteOptions.HIVE_URL_OPT_KEY -> "jdbc:hive2://<thrift server host>:<port>",
  DataSourceWriteOptions.HIVE_SYNC_ENABLED_OPT_KEY -> "true",
  DataSourceWriteOptions.HIVE_DATABASE_OPT_KEY -> "<the database>",
  DataSourceWriteOptions.HIVE_TABLE_OPT_KEY -> "<the table>",
  DataSourceWriteOptions.HIVE_PARTITION_FIELDS_OPT_KEY -> "<the partition field>",
  DataSourceWriteOptions.HIVE_PARTITION_EXTRACTOR_CLASS_OPT_KEY -> classOf[MultiPartKeysValueExtractor].getName
...
)
// Write the DataFrame as a Hudi dataset
// it will appear in hive (similar to saveAsTable..)
test_parquet_partition.write
  .format("org.apache.hudi")
  .option(DataSourceWriteOptions.OPERATION_OPT_KEY, DataSourceWriteOptions.INSERT_OPERATION_OPT_VAL)
  .options(hudiOptions)
  .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
  .save(hudiTablePath)
```

### Sync outside spark

use the bash script after running your hudi spark transformations [hudi documentation](https://hudi.apache.org/docs/writing_data/#syncing-to-hive)

````sh
cd hudi-hive

./run_sync_tool.sh  --jdbc-url jdbc:hive2:\/\/hiveserver:10000 --user hive --pass hive --partitioned-by partition --base-path <basePath> --database default --table <tableName>```)
```bash
cd hudi-hive

./run_sync_tool.sh  --jdbc-url jdbc:hive2:\/\/hiveserver:10000 --user hive --pass hive --partitioned-by partition --base-path <basePath> --database default --table <tableName>```
````